# PHP function without static can still be called just like a static

Tags: php, static-methods

I've noticed in PHP I can create a function without the static modifier but still call it as if it was a static function, just curious why this is allowed / what is actually happening.

```
class Foo {
   public function bar($i) {
       return $i + 1;
   }
}

Foo::bar(4); // 5
```

I would expect that the static modifier is required like:

```
class Foo {
   public static function bar($i) {
       return $i + 1;
   }
}

Foo::bar(4); // 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's for compatibility with PHP4 where the described behavior was how it actually worked (there was no `static` keyword).

You should be getting an `E_STRICT` error, though, unless your [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) is set to not display `E_STRICT`.